# Error when trying to delete redirection: can't remove unknown redirection

Tags: android, redirect, udp

I'm working on a simple 2 way chat app to learn about services. To simulate connections, I often run 2 emulators from Android Studio and do:

```
telnet localhost 5554
redir add udp:6667:6666
quit
telnet localhost 5556
redir add udp:6668:6666
quit
```

in the terminal. I do:

`redir list`

and get:

```
udp:6667 => 6666
udp:6668 => 6666
```

among other previous redirections. According to the android developer's site, to delete a redirection, I can do:

```
redir del udp:6667
```

but I end up always getting "KO: can't remove unknown redirection (udp:*port*) no matter which of the ports in the list I try.

It seems like a simple command! I'm not sure what can possibly causing this.